# Detect successful deletion by imap_delete() and imap_expunge()

Tags: php, imap

I am currently behind an unstable network. Network disconnection frequently happens.

> Is there a way to find whether imap_delete used along with
>   imap_expunge actually deleted the mail because imap_delete always
>   returns true no matter what.

I tried setting up a custom error handler but found out that neither any exception nor any warning or any error is being issued by imap_delete() or imap_expunge()

Answer (score 1):

One can never be completely sure:  imap_delete will set a \Deleted flag.

There's a couple different scenarios:
Case 1:

```
1) The `STORE` command was received by the server
2) We received an `OK`.
```

If you receive an OK from the server, you can be sure the server accepted the command (although, the message may not even exist, and setting flags on a non existent message is not necessarily an error)

Case 2:

```
1) The `STOR`E command was received by the server
2) We did not receive the `OK` due to network failure
```

In this case, you cannot be sure whether the message was marked deleted or not, since you didn't receive an OK.  In this case, you should reissue the delete when you reconnect.

Case 3:

```
1) The `STORE` command was not received by the server.
2) We did not receive `OK` due to network failure
```

This is indistinguishable from the previous case.  You should reissue the delete.  Storing the flag again may be redundant, but it won't hurt anything.

I would expect that the latter two cases would cause some sort of error, in which case it's safe to reissue the commands.  Hopefully someone who uses the PHP library can chime in on that.

Comment: imap_delete() doesn't returns anything.. How can I receive OK command ? Kindly tell..

Comment: Presumably if it returns it was successful? I don't know how exceptions work in PHP

Comment: That's the problem... neither imap_delete() nor imap_expunge() doesn't returns anything neither on success nor on failure. No exception, no warning, no notices nothing..